# Custom system for permissions with django

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions

I'm looking for a way to make my own system of groups and permissions in Django. I know that Django by default brings a system of groups and permits, but in my project due to teacher requirements I had to create my own models.

You can create new groups and add permissions to those groups, but since they are not the default models of django I cannot use the template-level functions such as 'perms.car.add_car' for example. What I mean by this? That at the template level, I don't know how to validate if the user has the permission. I hope I have explained myself well, I await your answers and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the current user's attributes from templates with `{{user.some_attribute}}`.

You can extend the default `django.contrib.auth.models.User` class with a one-to-one relationship with a `CustomUser` class you create, and access it from template the way described above, meaning:

```
{{ user.one_to_one_custom_user_field.some_attribute }}
```

For more info about extending `User` look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

In this `CustomUser` class add as you see fit:

- functions for interacting with the user group classes you created and verifying whether current user is in them or not, or has the right permissions
- flag variables (or any other indicative attribute) to indicate the user's groups and permissions.

Use one of these options as the `some_attribute` accessible from template.